# Can't use PHP value from jQuery.load() content

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm working on a project that uses jQuery modals that dynamically load their content on a button click.

I am having an issue using this loaded content like I would normally.

Here is an example of my problem

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    click function{
        load modal{
            open: $('#modalID').load('phpfile.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>');
    }
</script>
```

That all works fine, but when trying to use jQuery within the "phpfile.php" is where the problem lies

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$db = USE ID TO GET DATABASE INFO; //works fine here
?>
//ECHO SOME HTML HERE
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#buttonID').on('click', function(){
        alert('test <?php echo $id ?>');
    });
</script>
```

When I click the button, I get the alert but it just says test and I don't get the ID like I should.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions on this one!

Comment: Write your question better and with *real* code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have pasted pseudo code so it is difficult to say what is wrong in your code.

The following should work, give it a try:

File 1.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?
$id = "10";
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
    function(){
    $('#modalID').load('phpfile.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>');
    });
</script>

<div id = 'modalID'></div>
```

And phpfile.php:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<script>
    $('#buttonID').on('click', function(){
        alert('test <?php echo $id ?>');
    });
</script>

<input type="button" id = "buttonID" value="click me">
```

Comment: Turned out to be a dumb mistake on my part. I was using incorrect name for the item that I was trying to $_GET.
I would have pasted some actual code, but there is a lot of it and it is all split up into multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Please check on the do you have any errors in your browser's console. The above code should work. The possibilities are like if you don't get your $_GET['id'] or any script errors will prevent execution of your code.

I have created a sample php file which is working fine.

```
 <?php
  $id = rand();
 ?>
<button id="buttonID"> Click </button>
//ECHO SOME HTML HERE
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#buttonID').on('click', function(){
    alert('test <?php echo $id ?>');
  });
</script>
```